# Secure .bak file in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, backup

Please give me a complete way to secure my `.bak` file using SQL Server 2012 using either password or encryption. i tried the certificate way but it didn't work!

```
BACKUP DATABASE t2 
TO DISK = 'A:\test3.bak' 

USE master
GO
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'pwd1';
GO

USE MASTER
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE testEncCer
    WITH SUBJECT = 'test Backup Encrytion Certificate3';
GO

ALTER DATABASE t2
    SET ENCRYPTION ON;
    GO

USE t2
GO
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE testEncCer

BACKUP CERTIFICATE testEncCer
  TO FILE = '/var/opt/mssql/data/testEncCer.cer'  
  WITH PRIVATE KEY   
  (  
      FILE = '/var/opt/mssql/data/testEncCer.pvk',  
      ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'pwd1'  
  );  
  GO
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-encryption?view=sql-server-ver15 - *Starting in SQL Server **2014*** - guess you'll need to update your SQL Server

Comment: Otherwise you'll need to look at 3rd party apps, such as Redgate's SQL backup Pro, which can create encrypted backups. (I don't work for Redgate, but I do use the tool at the office.)

Comment: ok, i will try the RedGate, thank you

Answer (score 0):

you could take a backup of the database, temporarily/aux restore it (on anotherserver or on the same server with a different name), TDE (transparently encrypt) the temp/aux db and backup the temp/aux db adding a mediapassword too. The final backup will be protected by a mediapassword and it will require a certificate for restore. The original database remains operational and is not encrypted.

```
create database mytestdb
go

select *
into mytestdb.dbo.supersensitivedata
from master.dbo.spt_values;
go

select *
from mytestdb.dbo.supersensitivedata
go

--(aux) backup the database (for recreating a temp/aux db)
backup database mytestdb to disk = 'c:\temp\mytestdb_aux_full.bak'
go

--restore from the backup with a diff dbname
restore database mytestdbtde from disk = 'c:\temp\mytestdb_aux_full.bak'
with 
move 'mytestdb' to 'c:\temp\mytestdb.mdf',
move 'mytestdb_log' to 'c:\temp\mytestdb_log.ldf';
go

--create master cert&transparently encrypt the new db
use master
go

CREATE CERTIFICATE tdeEncCer
    WITH SUBJECT = 'testdb database Encryption Certificate';
GO
--backup the cert
BACKUP CERTIFICATE tdeEncCer
  TO FILE = 'c:\temp\tdeEncCer.cer'  
  WITH PRIVATE KEY   
  (  
      FILE = 'c:\temp\tdeEncCer.pvk',  
      ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'pwd1'  
  );  
  GO

--tde the secondary/aux db
use mytestdbtde
go

CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY  
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_128  
ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE tdeEncCer;  
GO 

ALTER DATABASE mytestdbtde  
SET ENCRYPTION ON;  
GO 

--backup again and also protect the backup with a mediapassword
backup database mytestdbtde to disk='c:\temp\mytestdb_tde_full.bak' with mediapassword='123456'
go

--drop the aux db
use master
go
drop database mytestdbtde
go

--lets read the backup file
restore filelistonly from disk='c:\temp\mytestdb_tde_full.bak';--access denied
--super secure mediapassword, we can read the bak
restore filelistonly from disk='c:\temp\mytestdb_tde_full.bak' with mediapassword='123456';

--simulate another server, which does not have the tdeEncCer
--drop tdeEncCer 
drop certificate tdeEncCer;
--super secure mediapassword....but the other server does not have the cert
restore filelistonly from disk='c:\temp\mytestdb_tde_full.bak' with mediapassword='123456';

--cleanup
drop database mytestdb;
--delete the files in c:\temp
```

Comment: the only error in your solution is the mediapassword in:
backup database mytestdbtde to disk='c:\temp\mytestdb_tde_full.bak' with mediapassword='123456', that gives the following error:Msg 3032, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
One or more of the options (mediapassword) are not supported for this statement. Review the documentation for supported options.   please tell me what should i do?

Comment: apparently mediapassword was discontinued from sql2012 (i thought it was supported). Just remove the "with mediapassword" references from the script, then operations with the bak will require the cert (mediapassword would be an added layer...not a secure one but a nice to have, but it is not possible in sql2012).